# magento get Catalog Price Rule or Discount Amount programmatically in the front-end by Rule Name

Tags: catalog, magento-1.5, promotions, magento

How can I get **Catalog Price Rule** programmatically in the front-end by **Rule Name**?
I need the **Discount Amount** of a particular price rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a way to make it but not by name and by id:

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1); 
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount();
```

and for price rule for shopping cart use

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1); 
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount();
```

Comment: `Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($name, 'name');` should work if you need to load by name

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you go by

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1); 
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1");
```

Then you can do

```
echo $rule->name;
echo $rule->description;
```

the above will give you the rules' name and description fields.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rule name:

```
$load_rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($order->getAppliedRuleIds());
$rule_name = $load_rule->getName();
```